# Q solution for deferred ajax and when() done()

Tags: durandal, q

Using Durandal SPA I have in my *shell.js* :

```
function activate() {
    datacontext.getUser(user);
    return datacontext
        .primeData()
        .then(boot)
        .fail(failedInitialization); //return for durandal 
}
```

THe **boot()** function depends on the result from **datacontext.getUser(user)**.

I would like to get the user credentials before activating. If **primeData()** doesn't do much (at the moment):

```
var primeData = function() {
        return Q.all([]);
               };
```

then **boot()** doesn't get the result from the datacontext:

```
var getUser = function(userObservable) {
            userObservable();
            var options =
            {
                url: 'api/user',
                type: 'GET',
                datatype: 'json'
            };

            return $.ajax(options).then(queryOk).fail(queryNotOk);

            function queryOk(data) {
                userObservable(model.user(data));
            }

            function queryNotOk(data, textStatus) {
               ...
            }
        };
```

The question is: How can I use Q instead of jQuery's *$.when().done()*:

```
 $.when(datacontext.getUser(user)).done(function() {
            return datacontext
                .primeData()
                .then(boot)
                .fail(failedInitialization);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest modification you could make is to use the `Q` function itself to "assimilate" the jQuery "promise returned by your `getUser` function:

```
Q(datacontext.getUser(user)).done(function() {
    return datacontext
        .primeData()
        .then(boot)
        .fail(failedInitialization);
});
```

Note that since Q promises chain, this can be made a bit simpler:

```
Q(datacontext.getUser(user))
    .then(datacontext.primeData)
    .then(boot)
    .fail(failedInitialization)
    .done();
```

A slightly better solution would be to do this assimilation inside the `getUser` function itself, so that it returns a Q promise instead of a jQuery "promise":

```
function getUser(userObservable) {
    userObservable();
    var options = {
        url: 'api/user',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json'
    };

    return Q($.ajax(options)).then(queryOk).fail(queryNotOk);

    function queryOk(data) {
        userObservable(model.user(data));
    }

    function queryNotOk(data, textStatus) {
       ...
    }
}

datacontext.getUser(user)
    .then(datacontext.primeData)
    .then(boot)
    .fail(failedInitialization)
    .done();
```